# How do I get the vendor name for each installed App/package?

Tags: android

I'm writing an App for Android which gets a list of all installed Apps and their details.  I get most of what I need with:

```
context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

What I can't seem to figure out is where I can get the name or id of the vendor who created the package/App.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to programmatically access that information. In fact I don't think the name of the vendor is stored within the apk file anywhere. The name that shows up as "Developer" in the Market is the name associated with the google account that uploaded the application. I think this value is stored by the Market infrastructure, rather than the application itself. Unfortunately there are currently no public APIs that grant access to the Market data.

If you are not necessarily concerned with the actual human readable name and you just aim to be able to programmatically tell whether the device has multiple applications from the same developer you might be able to glean this from the [signature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#signatures) field inside the PackageInfo object that you can get from `pm.getPackageInfo(String packageName, int flags);` I have very little experience with this though, I could be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a human viewable vendor name like "Acme Widgets, Inc".  Looking through my own AndroidManifest.xml I also do not see a place to set my company/vendor name.  Very strange this is not part of the manifest.